# How do I click an element in a list box where i need to scroll to it?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

thanks for trying to help me out.

I am trying run through a list box with categories.

When I click on the items in the list box everything is fine until the categories are below the visible list box. In that case it throws me this error:

> Element is not clickable at point (1121.5, 276). Other element would
>   receive the click:

So my question is this. **How do I click an element where i need to scroll a little in a list box, to be able to click it.**

A very short version of my code

```
listUl1 = browser.find_element_by_id('categoryManuallySelectLevel_1')
listCategories = []

# Fetch the id's
for child in listUl1.find_elements_by_xpath(".//"):
    listCategories.append(child.get_attribute('id'))

# click through the items in the list
for item in listCategories:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser,5,poll_frequency=.2).until(EC.visibility_of((By.ID, item)))
    element.click
```

A link to the site can be found here: http://www.guloggratis.dk/annonce/opret

If you have any questions do not hesitate to ask. I will instantly reply from my phone. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scroll the scroll bar using `ARROW_DOWN`

```
listBox = driver.find_element(By.id('categoryManuallySelectLevel_1'))
counter = 1
for item in listCategories:
    if counter % 4 == 0: # scroll every 4 elements or so
        listBox.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    element = WebDriverWait(browser,5,poll_frequency=.2).until(EC.visibility_of((By.ID, item)))
    element.click
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I tried your solution, but unfortunately it still doesn't scroll, but it is still able to click all other elements. :)

Comment: if you just want to scroll then you can use my answer scrollToElementAndClick method .. just remove click from that code and add Guy code over it .. may it help

Comment: I do need it to scroll and click. I should also mention that I am using firefox, so where it shouldn't need to click on points.

Comment: @JacobMolinNielsen Do you have any errors? or it just doesn't scroll?

Comment: Yes I still get the error: Element is not clickable at point (1121.5, 276). Other element would receive the click:

Comment: @JacobMolinNielsen I edited my answer, you can try to scroll the listbox using key down

Comment: Hi again, so I've managed to make it scroll a little, now i just need to tell script that it should scroll down in case it cannot find the element. I tried something like:
while browser.find_element_by_id(item).is_displayed() == False:
    listBox.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
But it just skips this code. :S

Comment: @JacobMolinNielsen And you get the `Element is not clickable` error? because it looks ok.

Comment: Hi I managed to get it working! I very much appreciate all of your help. I'll mark your answer as the solution. 

Comment: @JacobMolinNielsen Glad to hear it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need javaScriptexecutor for same.

below is the java method which can help you on same. refer it and use it in python. It will be quite similar in python to:-

```
private void scrollToElementAndClick(WebElement element) {
    int yScrollPosition = element.getLocation().getY();
    js.executeScript("window.scroll(0, " + yScrollPosition + ");");
    element.click();
}
```

If it will not work then use (Not recommended ):-

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",  driver.findElement(By.<your locator>));
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I cannot make it work with action script, I might try JavascriptExecutor, but I have a hard time finding some good resources online for Python. :/

Comment: Why do you say the second option is not recommended?

Comment: Because JavascriptExecutor directly working on DOM and it may cause a success of testcase while the testcase is fail in real scenarios ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robot Method as well for scrolling page down as below:

```
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        Robot robot3 = new Robot();
        robot3.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
        robot3.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);

        Thread.sleep(1000);

    element = WebDriverWait(browser,5,poll_frequency=.2).until(EC.visibility_of((By.ID, item)))
    element.click
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I am not using Java, but I am strongly considering it as I see the majority of the Selenium community are using it.